# How to search text for multiple strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have a text string as follows:

```
$input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae magna vel neque tincidunt.";
add_filter('hello_text', 'sample'); 
add_filter('goodbye_text', 'sample');
```

I need to search the string for `"add_filter('***'"` and get the *** text. If the string contains multiple different *** strings, I need to get them as well and save them to an array.

So the `$input` string above would generate: `array('hello_text','goodbye_text')`

I think I can use `stripos ()` but I'm not sure how I would find this text pattern, as the *** text will be different every time.

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on dekameron's answer but makes the regular expression more generic.

```
<?php

$input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit add_filter('hello_text', 'sample'). Sed vitae magna add_filter('goodbye_text', 'sample') vel neque tincidunt.";

preg_match_all( "/add_filter\s*?\(\s*?'(.+?)'/ui", $input, $matches );

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Hook names are not restricted to just basic characters such as letters, numbers, underscore, etc. (Advanced Custom Fields is one plugin that uses forward slashes in the hook names). This regular expression will handle generic hook names (however, it won't handle escaped single quotes). Additionally, this will handle cases where the spacing between the "add_function", the opening paren, and the hook argument changes.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! Also, I didn't realize hook names can have slashes etc. in them! Now I have to learn what that regular expression is doing...

Comment: @harvey, I suggest using regex101.com to test and examine regular expressions, https://regex101.com/r/NGBWah/1

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function find_filters($string)
{
    if (!preg_match_all("|add_filter\('([a-z0-9_]+)'|ui", $string, $matches)) {
        return [];
    }

    return array_unique($matches[1]);
}

$input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit add_filter('hellotext', 'sample'). Sed vitae magna add_filter('goodbye_text', 'sample') vel neque tincidunt.";

$result = find_filters($input);
var_dump($result);
```